# HOW to get value stored in a python variable if only its address is given?

Tags: python-2.7

If a variable has address '20754060', how can we get the value stored in that address?

```
a=20754060                  #consist of address of some variable
```

how can we get value stored in '20754060' location

Comment: AFAIK python does not have the concept of pointers and addresses... Where did you get this assignment from?

Comment: Can you explain the actual problem; or give more details. Right now this problem is looking like something for another language, and not Python.

Answer (score 0):

You probably cannot, and even if you can - you really shouldn't. Screwing around with memory content, ignoring or standing in way of GC is WRONG and probably will cause some weird errors.

Answer (score 0):

As people already mentioned: this is so wrong ;)

However, this is how you do it (just a start).

```
from ctypes import *
# create c_int (only ctype addresses work)
a = c_int(423)
# get address of a
address = addressof(a)
#print address (just for fun)
print address
# print content of address (this works for size 1)
print c_char_p(address)
#check that it is the same (423 is 1a7 in hex. Note MSB vs LSB)
print hex(423)
```

This prints out:

```
35746280
c_char_p('\xa7\x01')
0x1a7
```

The above works only in the case of ctype objects like c_int (=ctypes.c_int).

c_char_p function gets the values one byte at the time. For more complicated objects, things get really ugly really fast and probably there is a limit at some point. But if you want, start reading here:

http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html

Answer (score 0):

try this, in my case it is working.

```
address = id(variable)
```

this gives the id of the variable, and use this id to check the value of the variable

```
ctypes.cast(address, ctypes.py_object).value
```